# How do I get what option the user selected?

Tags: php, html, mysql, select, selection

I want to get what option the user selected and the "value" of that `<option>` to be stored in his account (I have a MySQL register system).

I made the table, everything is alright, username works perfectly, password works perfectly, but I got stuck at the selection part:

```
<td>team:</td>
<td>
    <select name="teamlist" form="regform">
        <option value="AstraGiu">Astra Giurgiu</option>
        <option value="FCBotosani">FC Botosani</option>
        <option value="FCBrasov">FC Brasov</option>
        <option value="CeahlaulPN">Ceahlaul Piatra Neamt</option>
        <option value="CFRCluj">CFR Cluj</option>
        <option value="DinamoBuc">Dinamo Bucuresti</option>
        <option value="FarulCta">Farul Constanta</option>
        <option value="GazMetanM">Gaz Metan Medias</option>
        <option value="OtelulGal">Otelul Galati</option>
        <option value="PanduriiTgJiu">Pandurii Targu-Jiu</option>
        <option value="PetrolulPlo">Petrolul Ploiesti</option>
        <option value="RapidBuc">Rapid Bucuresti</option>
        <option value="SteauaBuc">Steaua Bucuresti</option>
        <option value="UCluj">Universitatea Cluj</option>
        <option value="UCraiova">Universitatea Craiova</option>
        <option value="UTAArad">UTA Arad</option>
        <option value="FCVaslui">FC Vaslui</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

After the user enters their username, pass, and selects the team, I have made this button...

```
<td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="register"/></td>
```

And if this helps you, here's how I store it..

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $username = secure('username');
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        $team = secure('team');

        if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
            echo "The username field is empty.";
        } else {
            if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
                echo "The password field is empty.";
            } else {
                if (empty($_POST['team'])) {
                    echo "The team field is empty.";
                } else {
                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '". $username ."'") or die(mysql_error());
                    if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 1){
                        echo "The username already exists.";    
                    } else {
                        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES(NULL, '". $username ."', '". $password ."', '". team ."')") or die(mysql_error());
                        echo "Successfully registered.";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

How do I get what team he selected and store the "value" of that team (option) in the MySQL database?

Comment: Please format your code so that it's not all the way over there....

Comment: Use print_r($_POST) to see the values in the post request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

`$_POST['teamlist']`

I'm assuming your `secure` function accepts the name of a form element, so you could change this line:

```
$team = secure('teamlist');
```

and change this:

```
if (empty($_POST['teamlist'])) {
    echo "The team field is empty.";
}
```

Although I see in your validation that you're subscribing to the [arrow anti-pattern](http://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2009/10/05/the-arrow-anti-pattern/)

Comment: Also, in the database, should "team" be a "VARCHAR"?

Comment: The way you have the values structured, yes.  If you're planning on representing teams in a table in your database, then you should probably restructure how you're outputting it (query teams from db, iterate over results in a while loop) and then you can use the primary key as the value which may be an integer.  In that case you'd have an integer foreign key to that table.  As it is, your values are strings so the DB would store a varchar.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm almost done and I understood your answer. But what you mean't by `$_POST['teamlist']` ? Should that be the form's action or what?

Comment: That would be how you would reference what team the user chose in your form handler.  It's based on the fact that you used `teamlist` as the name attribute in your select element.  Your original code uses `$_POST['team']` instead.

Comment: There we go! It works. Thanks a lot, I didn't expect this to be solved so fast. Again, thanks !